# Can the Orochick (Wondrous Egg) be acquired? If so, how?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I have the Orokeet (Unusual Egg) and Orosquab (Mysterious Egg) pets, and I've been looking for information on how to get the [Orochick](http://www.torhead.com/item/92IpA11/orochick) ([Wonderous Egg](http://www.torhead.com/item/crpCSAv/wonderous-egg)).  Unfortunately, everything I've found seems unreliable.  I've seen claims that:

- It's not available in-game
- It's in-game but no one has found it yet ([source](http://www.swtor.com/community/showpost.php?p=4783093&postcount=140))
- The Wonderous Egg drops from Warlord Kephess in the Explosive Conflict operation ([source](http://www.swtor.com/community/showthread.php?t=409618))
- It drops from the Orobirds in EC story mode when you kill them

None of this has been accompanied by screenshots or a link to official statements from BioWare or anything like that.

Does anyone have this pet and know how to get it?  Or does anyone happen to know of more reliable / official information?  Please share :)

Comment: Hmm found some [seemingly better info](http://www.swtor.com/community/showpost.php?p=4741887&postcount=1) but still really speculative...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update: A dev got back to me with this:

> So I passed everything on to our dev folk for investigation, I can confirm for you that no one has ever gotten the wondrous egg. My only guess can be that folks may have gotten it mixed up with the other egg (an easy mixup for sure). I also fear that the information you received from our CS agents appears to be incorrect, at least as far as we can tell, **no one has ever gotten the egg nor has it been distributed in-game**.

---

THANK YOU FOR ASKING THIS. I posted the first sourced link so I'll just add that BioWare themselves said it was ingame when [they mentioned how it could now be sold on the GTN in Patch Notes 1.2.2](http://www.swtor.com/patchnotes/1.2.2/512012).

As for the egg--yeah, there's been A LOT of rumors without any proof. The most spread around one is that it drops from HM Kephess, but there has been absolutely no proof at all.

Other rumors are that it drops from Kephess anywhere in EC, that it just drops in EC (but from what is unknown), and that after you defeat Kephess (no difficulty specified), a nest spawns somewhere in the instance and an egg spawns in it. I've been all of the instance so I doubt it but bleh.

Comment: I found the specific patch notes you were referring to and linked it, thanks!